# How to implement breadcrumb in MVC 4 for one controller but linking several actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, breadcrumbs

So I have very simple code structure I have only one controller (excluding the login and base controllers) - the `Home` controller and all actions that I call are from there. I had to implement a breadcrumb and since it's only one controller I decided that I won't use stuff like `mvcsitemapprovider` or something else of that matter but instead stick to something simple like this one that I now have :

```
 @if(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] != "Index")
        {
            <div class="top-header-links">
                @Html.ActionLink(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()) 
            </div>
        }
        <div class="top-header-links">
            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
        </div>
```

Which actually is not much at all, but I was satisfied since. But now I see that there are some certain cases like `Home/News` and `Home/ShortNews` which are both actions in my `Home` controller so one could say that they are on the same level, but still the logical connection is that `ShortNews` is a node of the more general `News` so in my breadcrumb I ultimately would like to have `>Home>News>ShortNews` but in the way it's implemented now obviously it's not gonna happen.

So what I can think about now is using `ViewBag.SecondAction` or something and populate it in those actions that I know that are called from inside another action and just put one more check in my `_Layout` page for `if (ViewBag.SecondAction != null)` and then add what I want. For now this would do the job but as I see it, it doesn't seem scalable, and if the project grows I think this would be hard to maintain (and probably no very efficient as there may be more conditions than there are now). So still I'm looking for some standard solution, by standard I mean that I would be happy if I don't have to install third party software and just write the code myself but also I want it to be a little more generic, at least to handle this case that I've described.

Since most of the suggestions I saw were to just use `mvcsitemapprovider` I want to know if I can modify my code so that I get the desired result and if I only want to include one more action is there an easy way to do this, at least easier than using `mvcsitemapprovider`?

Comment: MvcSiteMapProvider isn't easy? Setup the xml sitemap and call `@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()` it doesn't get much easier. You want scalable but without all the benefits of a vetted library. You're going to spend more time trying to re-invent the wheel; just take the half hour and get past the learning curve and move on.

Comment: @BradChristie Well, I am considering that too, if you want you can even post it as answer. This is the first time I have something to do with breadcrumbs so I had to kinda look around. `MvcSiteMapProvider` just provides much more like SEO and what not so I was thinking that maybe there is some other tool dedicated only to create breadcrumbs. But if that is the case indeed (like you say it is) I may as well just spend the time as you suggest and get used of what is already done.

Comment: it's big [read as "flexible"] but you don't have to use everything. However, setting up the `mvc.sitemap` and simply calling the helper is about as easy as it gets for a breadcrumb. Moreover, it completely flexible, so any future growth will be light years easier than coming up with the next `ViewBag` property or interrogating `RouteData`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
@{
    @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "HomeController")

    if (Html.IsCurrentAction("News", "HomeController"))
    {
        @:> News
    }

    if (Html.IsCurrentAction("ShortNews", "HomeController"))
    {
        @:> @Html.ActionLink("News", "News", "HomeController")
        @:> Short News
    }
```

I use a Html helper method to determine if its the current action. Mine is a bit more in-depth, checking not only route values but also query string parameters, and it's not bullet proof, but you could extend it for your purposes.

```
 public static bool IsCurrentAction(this HtmlHelper helper, string actionName,
     string controllerName)
 {
     var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values);
     //use this to then check if its current action/controller
```